# moving along a grid with allowable moves of right, up and down

Tags: matlab, path, grid, path-finding

How many different ways exist in order to go from A to D.
How can I code it in matlab?
what if some of the paths such as 6 and 7 paths are blocked?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvnZS.png)

Comment: Only right up and down movements are allowed.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please consider [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Users are much more likely to help if you (1) show some [research effort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) on your own, and (2) learn [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) (good) questions around here. Please provide a [mre] to your _specific_ problem. What have you tried so far? Please show any relevant code.